# I am not able to understand the following code

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

```
 View listItemView = convertView;
      if(listItemView == null) {
          listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
```

I am not able to understand the above code.This code is a portion of making custom ArrayAdapter.Following is the Custom ArrayAdapter code of a particular project.

```
public class AndroidFlavorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AndroidFlavor> {

private static final String LOG_TAG = AndroidFlavorAdapter.class.getSimpleName();


public AndroidFlavorAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<AndroidFlavor> androidFlavors) {

    super(context, 0, androidFlavors);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View listItemView = convertView;
    if(listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }


    AndroidFlavor currentAndroidFlavor = getItem(position);

    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.version_name);

    nameTextView.setText(currentAndroidFlavor.getVersionName());

    TextView numberTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.version_number);
    numberTextView.setText(currentAndroidFlavor.getVersionNumber());


    ImageView iconView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_icon);

    iconView.setImageResource(currentAndroidFlavor.getImageResourceId());


    return listItemView;
}
```

}

Why the listItemView is assigned with convertView.Why is it checked whether it is null or not and the usage of LayoutInflator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 10 items in your list adapter, `getView` will be called 10 times with position 0 to 9. Basically, `getView` method creates a view that will be inflated in the particular position (ie. 0 to 9). `getView` method will be repeated if something happening in UI (eg. scrolling). At first the `convertView` is `null` since nothing is inflated yet and you are going to inflate now. Next time onwards `convertView` won't be null (because you already inflated) and all you have to do is, update the content of `convertView`. They had assigned the `convertView` to local variable `listItemView` and made changes over that.

Answer (score 0):

convertView is one item of your listView.

getView It will repeat  your custum layout + convertView

that is one item your custom listView

Comment: You mean to say that, we are adding our custom layout with a list view and which is equal or getting binded by getView method??

Answer (score 0):

Basically the `getView` method is the one who gets called every time you need to bind your custom layout for any `ListView` position.
The code: `View listItemView = convertView;` just helps you understand that `converView` is your list item view. So if in that position this is null the `getView` method will bind that `ListView` position with your custom layout.